# What's a good way to handle this simple example in CSS?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Let's say I have the following layout on some pages:

```
               Title: Some Title   
              Author: Some Author   
Author Date of Birth: Date of birth
```

Notes:

- Left side text is right-aligned and bold.
- Used on several different pages.
- The right side can contain input controls at some point.

What would be the most appropriate method to apply in this situation?  I can think of a few options (assume CSS applied in external style sheet):

**Table**

Simple, easy, but I'm not sure this would be considered a good use of tables.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Title</td>
  <td>Some Title</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

**Div + Classes**

I feel like this is a case of divitis and classitis rolled into one.

```
<div class="information">
 <div class="title">Title</div><div class="value">Some Title</div>
</div>
```

**Container Div**

This feels more like the right path but I'm not sure.

```
<div class="information">
 <strong>Title</strong> <span>Some Title</span>
</div>
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Table is best practice in this case.

Comment: @mcb actually, I think the `table` one is the worst, due to Screen Readers compatibility.  I prefer the `div + classes` one.

Comment: Instead of tables you could also try definition lists in your case: http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/definition/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right in you saying you want to use a table, but don't want to use. In this case i don't think a table is correct either. I personally only use tables if i need to organize data nicely. Because you have so much, a bunch of floated divs everywhere is more of a hassle then just using a table.

Because this is only two columns I would say use use two divs with floats or use two spans, instead of strong use a span and then style it with css.

Answer (score 5):

I think a good semantic choice here is the `dl` (description list) element.

http://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element

```
<dl>
    <dt>Title</dt>
    <dd>Some Title</dd>

    <dt>Author</dt>
    <dd>Some Author</dd>

    <dt>Author Date of Birth</dt>
    <dd>Date of birth</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a table, this is one of the few instances where using a table actually isn
't all that wrong. You're not using it for layout but text markup.

Then apply a class to every first column and in css make that class have `text-align: right;` which applies to that column.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly a good example of when to use tables.

It's tabular data.

Use `th`s for the first columns cells to be able to style it.

I even think `th`s are bold by default. Not sure about all browsers though so wouldn't hurt to style them bold to be sure :).

Answer (score 0):

A table is a means of arranging data in rows and columns.

And this is what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Definition list would be semantically correct.

```
  <dl>
     <dt>Title:</dt>
     <dd>Some Title<dd>

     <dt>Author:</dt>
     <dd>Some Author</dd>

     <dt>Author Date of Birth:</dt>
     <dd>Date of birth</dd>
  </dl>
```

See W3C for more details - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp